# Storing email address with SHA512 email address, would a substring of the sha512 value be safer to store with the email address?

Tags: email, hash, sha512

I am marketing to interested users with their provided email address.  To make their hyperlink unique to their "offer", I plan to use SHA512 of their email address in their link address.  Since the user would have the email address and now the SHA512 value, it was suggested to substring the SHA512 value instead of using the whole SHA512 value.  Is that safer since the user would not have the original value and the complete hashed value?

We're aware that there are numerous solutions to make the SHA512 hash more secure, but if the substring method would work, that's what we want to implement.

Comment: Using a hash of any sort seems like it could be easily reverse engineered.  I'd only need a couple of links and I could figure it out for any email, even truncated.  A UUID is completely unpredictable from a hacking perspective.  You store the UUID with the user and check it when the user comes in.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What are you concerned about? Users already know their emails, and they can hash it if they want, so you are not telling them anything new. I you rely on the hash as the only access control mechanism, then yes, it's broken, as someone can just put in someone else's email hash. BTW. if you only store part of the hash, it may not be unique anymore, making this even more broken for authentication.